# Kafka topic details not displaying in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have written a topic in Kafka as `my-topic` and I am trying to fetch the information of topic in spark. But I am facing some difficulty in displaying Kafka topic details as I am getting long list of errors. I am using java for fetching data.

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String s[]) throws InterruptedException{
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Sampleapp");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(10));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "Different id is allotted for different stream");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("my-topic");

    final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
      KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc,
        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
      );

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> jPairDStream =  stream.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                }
            });

    jPairDStream.foreachRDD(jPairRDD -> {
           jPairRDD.foreach(rdd -> {
                System.out.println("key="+rdd._1()+" value="+rdd._2());
            });
        });

    jssc.start();            
    jssc.awaitTermination(); 

    stream.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                }
            });
}
```

Below is the Error I am getting:

> Using Spark's default log4j profile:
>   org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO
>   SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0 17/09/04 11:41:15 WARN
>   NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 17/09/04
>   11:41:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: 11014525
>   17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to:
>   11014525 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls
>   groups to:  17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify
>   acls groups to:  17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO SecurityManager:
>   SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users 
>   with view permissions: Set(11014525); groups with view permissions:
>   Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(11014525); groups with
>   modify permissions: Set() 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO Utils: Successfully
>   started service 'sparkDriver' on port 56668. 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO
>   SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO
>   SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO
>   BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using
>   org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology
>   information 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:
>   BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up 17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO DiskBlockManager:
>   Created local directory at
>   C:\Users\11014525\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-cba489b9-2458-455a-8c03-4c4395a01d44
>   17/09/04 11:41:15 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity
>   896.4 MB 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO Utils: Successfully
>   started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040. 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO
>   SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at
>   http://172.16.202.21:4040 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO Executor: Starting
>   executor ID driver on host localhost 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO Utils:
>   Successfully started service
>   'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port
>   56689. 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 172.16.202.21:56689 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO BlockManager:
>   Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block
>   replication policy 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO BlockManagerMaster:
>   Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.202.21, 56689,
>   None) 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering
>   block manager 172.16.202.21:56689 with 896.4 MB RAM,
>   BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.202.21, 56689, None) 17/09/04 11:41:16
>   INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
>   BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.202.21, 56689, None) 17/09/04 11:41:16
>   INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver,
>   172.16.202.21, 56689, None) 17/09/04 11:41:16 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding enable.auto.commit to false for executor 17/09/04 11:41:16
>   WARN KafkaUtils: overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding executor group.id to
>   spark-executor-Different id is allotted for different stream 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding receive.buffer.bytes to 65536 see
>   KAFKA-3135 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Slide time
>   = 10000 ms 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO
>   DirectKafkaInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null 17/09/04 11:41:16
>   INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Remember interval = 10000 ms 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Initialized and validated
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream@23a3407b
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 10000 ms 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO MappedDStream: Remember interval = 10000 ms
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@140030a9 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO ForEachDStream: Slide time = 10000 ms 17/09/04 11:41:16
>   INFO ForEachDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO ForEachDStream: Remember interval = 10000 ms 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@65041548 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking
>   it as stopped org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing
>   required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no
>   default value.    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:124)    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.consumer(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:75)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
>     at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>     at ... run in separate thread using org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils
>   ... ()    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:578)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:556)
>     at
>   Json.ExcelToJson.SparkConsumingKafka.main(SparkConsumingKafka.java:56)
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker stopped
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for JobGenerator
>   after time -1 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO JobGenerator: Stopped
>   JobGenerator 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO JobScheduler: Stopped JobScheduler
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required
>   configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default
>   value.    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:124)    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.consumer(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:75)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
>     at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
>     at
>   scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>     at ... run in separate thread using org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils
>   ... ()    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:578)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:556)
>     at
>   Json.ExcelToJson.SparkConsumingKafka.main(SparkConsumingKafka.java:56)
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown
>   hook 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at
>   http://172.16.202.21:4040 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO
>   MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint
>   stopped! 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
>   17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped 17/09/04
>   11:41:16 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:
>   OutputCommitCoordinator stopped! 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO SparkContext:
>   Successfully stopped SparkContext 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO
>   ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called 17/09/04 11:41:16 INFO
>   ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
>   C:\Users\11014525\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-37334cdc-9680-4801-8e50-ef3024ed1d8a

pom.xml

> org.apache.spark
>       spark-streaming_2.11
>       2.1.0 
>               
>                     commons-lang
>                     commons-lang
>                     2.6
>               
>               
>       org.apache.kafka
>       kafka_2.10
>       0.8.2.0  
>               org.apache.spark
>               spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10
>               2.1.1

Comment: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default value.
that might have something to do with it

Comment: @bleedcode I have edited my answer below based on the pom.xml details you have provided. Please try it and let me know if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the log, your spark version is 2.1.0. You have not shared the build file having other dependencies. It looks like you have both `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.1.0.jar` and `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.jar` in classpath and it is loading the wrong class. If you are using maven then you would need dependencies like below. Please check and update your project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**

As you have edited the question and posted the dependencies I am editing my Answer. You are using Kafka version `0.8.*` while your spark-streaming-kafka version is `0.10.*`. Please use same version for Kafka dependencies. Please use below dependency for `org.apache.kafka`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please check your build if old jar is still there. Please use maven update project and clean build.